# How to export query result to a text files and create blocks of data at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, visual-studio

I was assign a project where my requirement is to build a text file out of data coming from a DB2 database, so far I got all the data and layout that I need for the file except for one part.  Each record on the file is identified by a constant at the beginning of the record, the first two record types “A” and “B” are hard coded information so no data from DB here.

Example:

```
AASNxxxxxxxxONT0010585567 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

T201201190945xxxxxxxxxxxx          201201241245
```

The next record on the file is has some data coming from the DB and it represents a store number.

Example:

```
B               1042                     000
```

This record should be repeated for every store in the query.

This next set of record are cartons for that store number on record type “B”, the number of records varies depending on the day/load it could be more or less

```
C1042333375563                        14.300000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333375564                        24.100000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333375768                        35.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333375769                        37.980000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376321                        26.120000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376322                        25.860000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376323                        36.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376324                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376325                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376326                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376327                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376328                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376329                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376330                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376331                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376332                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
```

So far everything is going as I want until this point. The next record in the file should the total number of cartons for the store

Example:

```
D16000000000000000000
```

When you put everything together it should look like this

```
B               1042                     000
C1042333375563                        14.300000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333375564                        24.100000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333375768                        35.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333375769                        37.980000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376321                        26.120000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376322                        25.860000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376323                        36.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376324                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376325                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376326                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376327                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376328                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376329                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376330                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376331                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376332                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
D16000000000000000000
```

I will like this to repeat for every store that results from the query. Instead what I’m getting is this

```
B               1042                     000
C1042333375563                        14.300000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333375564                        24.100000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333375768                        35.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333375769                        37.980000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376321                        26.120000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376322                        25.860000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376323                        36.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376324                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376325                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376326                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376327                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376328                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376329                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376330                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376331                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376332                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333362820                        15.940000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333362821                        25.020000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363628                        34.120000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363629                        30.760000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363833                        5.860000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363834                        25.900000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363835                        25.760000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363836                        36.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363837                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363838                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363839                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363840                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363841                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363842                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1114333360163                        30.740000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1114333360164                        29.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1114333360165                        31.540000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1114333360166                        39.780000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1114333360167                        33.680000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1114333360168                        24.780000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1114333360169                        29.860000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1114333360706                        15.960000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1114333361051                        25.680000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1114333361052                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1114333361053                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1114333361054                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1114333361055                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333382930                        27.060000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333382931                        20.560000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383074                        25.180000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383075                        30.420000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383077                        28.420000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383406                        25.980000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383407                        26.020000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383408                        25.760000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383409                        36.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383410                        36.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383411                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383412                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383413                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383414                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383415                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383416                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383417                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383418                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1118333383419                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1136333360998                        22.540000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1136333361237                        31.780000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1136333361238                        31.260000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1136333361689                        26.060000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1136333361690                        25.880000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1136333361691                        36.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1136333361692                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1136333361693                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1136333361694                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1136333361695                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1136333361696                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1136333361697                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1136333361698                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333366296                        20.080000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333366917                        26.920000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333366918                        31.120000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333366919                        36.780000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333366920                        46.860000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333366921                        31.700000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333366922                        31.420000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333367268                        26.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333367269                        25.820000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333367270                        36.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333367271                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333367272                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333367273                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333367274                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333367275                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1289333367276                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333340832                        19.660000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333340833                        19.840000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341219                        35.540000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341220                        33.640000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341221                        29.360000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341222                        28.520000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341223                        30.420000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341224                        33.340000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341225                        27.220000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341226                        31.640000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341227                        30.680000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341228                        29.400000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341558                        26.040000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341559                        24.900000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341560                        36.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341561                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341562                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341563                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341564                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341565                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341566                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1519333341567                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350211                        30.080000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350212                        47.420000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350213                        35.480000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350214                        33.640000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350215                        30.760000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350216                        38.140000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350219                        33.400000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350268                        20.380000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350269                        8.820000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350270                        23.940000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350271                        20.580000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350646                        26.020000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350647                        26.120000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350648                        25.800000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350649                        36.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350650                        36.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350651                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350652                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350653                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350654                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350655                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350656                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350657                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350658                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1523333350659                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
D16000000000000000000
```

As you can see there is only one record type “B” and record type “D” when I should have one for each store. The store number is the first 4 digits after the record type “C” character.

Here is an example of how it should look with multiple stores:

```
AASNxxxxxxxxONT0010585567 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
T201201190945xxxxxxxxxxxx          201201241245
B               1042                     000
C1042333375563                        14.300000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333375564                        24.100000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333375768                        35.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333375769                        37.980000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376321                        26.120000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376322                        25.860000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376323                        36.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376324                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376325                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376326                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376327                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376328                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376329                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376330                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376331                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1042333376332                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
D16000000000000000000
B               1084                     000
C1084333362820                        15.940000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333362821                        25.020000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363628                        34.120000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363629                        30.760000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363833                        5.860000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363834                        25.900000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363835                        25.760000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363836                        36.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363837                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363838                        33.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363839                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363840                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363841                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
C1084333363842                        1.000000000000Y               00000000000000000000
D14000000000000000000
```

How can I achieve this? Is this possible? I’m sure it is but I just can’t figure out. Here is my code:

```
//Declare the ConnectionString
odbccon.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PkMS"];

//Create Physical File
w = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\jorge.mejia\\Documents\\ThirdParty_ASN\\Test Files\\xxxxASN_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss") + ".txt");

//Create Header Record - Type "A"
w.WriteLine(constantA + fileidentifier + clientidentifier + primaryscac + dcidentifier + shipmentID + masterBOL + buildingID);

//Create Load Record - Type "T"
w.WriteLine(constantT + trailerclosedate + trailerclosetime + trailernumber + sealnumber + expectedarrivaldate + expectedarrivaltime + trailerserialnumber + carrier);


odbccon.Open();
OdbcCommand getstore = new OdbcCommand("select count(*) as totalstorecartons, chstor from wm242basd.chcart00 where chldno = '0010585567' group by chstor order by chstor", odbccon);
OdbcDataReader odbcr2 = getstore.ExecuteReader();
while (odbcr2.Read())
{
    storenumber = odbcr2["chstor"].ToString();
    totalstorecartons = odbcr2["totalstorecartons"].ToString();


    //Create Store Record - Type "B"
    w.WriteLine(constantB + deliverycarrierSCAC + clientroute + businesscode + storenumber + clientbolnumber + terminalcode + deliverydays + deliverystarttime + deliveryendtime + carrierpro + expecteddeliverydate);

    OdbcCommand getcartons = new OdbcCommand("select chcasn, chstor, chacwt from wm242basd.chcart00 where chldno = '0010585567' order by chstor", odbccon);
    OdbcDataReader odbcr = getcartons.ExecuteReader();
    while (odbcr.Read())
    {
        cartonnumber = odbcr["chcasn"].ToString() + "                 ";
        storenumber = odbcr["chstor"].ToString() + "  ";
        weightlbs = odbcr["chacwt"].ToString();


        //Create Store Record - Type "C"
        w.WriteLine(constantC + cartonnumber + weightlbs + cubicfeet + conveyable + specialhandling + cartonvalue + cartonretail + units + palletnumber);
    }

    //Create Store Record - Type "D"
    w.WriteLine(constantD + totalstorecartons + totalstoreweight + totalstorecubicfeet);
}

OdbcCommand getloadtotal = new OdbcCommand("select count(*) as totaltrailercartons, sum(chacwt) as totaltrailerweight from wm242basd.chcart00 where chldno = '0010585567'", odbccon);
OdbcDataReader odbcr3 = getloadtotal.ExecuteReader();
while (odbcr3.Read())
{
    totaltrailercartons = odbcr3["totaltrailercartons"].ToString();
    totaltrailerweight = odbcr3["totaltrailerweight"].ToString();
}

//Create Store Record - Type "E"
w.WriteLine(constantE + totaltrailercartons + totaltrailerweight + totaltrailercubicfeet);

//Maintenance and Close
w.Flush();
w.Close();
```

Any help that you could provide will be really appreciate it.

Comment: You really need to shorten up your examples within your question. You can't fully read the question without a lot of scrolling.

Comment: Speaking as someone who does a lot of importing of data, if someone gave me a file like that to import I would shoot them. Before I spent a lot of time on this, I would ensure that the people who need this information really would prefer to get it in that format. Sometimes the people who come up with these requirements have talked to neither the provider or the receiver of the information to make sure this is the best format. (if it is going to a mainframe it might be) We return file to the client and request in a better format and they are often "oh ok, we didn't know that would be easier".

Comment: I've done that, and it was actually worse before, and yes this is going to a mainframe.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have 2 problems.  One, you are only going through the outer loop one time  I'm not sure why that is, but I can help you with the second problem.  The second problem is that the query for the inner loop needs to be limited to one group of data at a time.

In your getcartons query: `select chcasn, chstor, chacwt from wm242basd.chcart00 where chldno = '0010585567' order by chstor` you should have a condition which limits the results to the current storenumber, instead of ordering by the store number again.  I'm not familiar with Odbc, but with Oracle I would do something like this:

```
while (odbcr2.Read()) 
{ 
    storenumber = odbcr2["chstor"].ToString(); 
    totalstorecartons = odbcr2["totalstorecartons"].ToString(); 


    //Create Store Record - Type "B" 
    w.WriteLine(constantB + deliverycarrierSCAC + clientroute + businesscode + storenumber + clientbolnumber + terminalcode + deliverydays + deliverystarttime + deliveryendtime + carrierpro + expecteddeliverydate); 

    OdbcCommand getcartons = new OdbcCommand("select chcasn, chstor, chacwt from wm242basd.chcart00 where chldno = '0010585567' and chstor = :storeNumber", odbccon); 
    getcartons.AddParameter("storeNumber", storenumber);
    OdbcDataReader odbcr = getcartons.ExecuteReader(); 
    while (odbcr.Read()) 
    { 
        cartonnumber = odbcr["chcasn"].ToString() + "                 "; 
        storenumber = odbcr["chstor"].ToString() + "  "; 
        weightlbs = odbcr["chacwt"].ToString(); 


        //Create Store Record - Type "C" 
        w.WriteLine(constantC + cartonnumber + weightlbs + cubicfeet + conveyable + specialhandling + cartonvalue + cartonretail + units + palletnumber); 
    } 

    //Create Store Record - Type "D" 
    w.WriteLine(constantD + totalstorecartons + totalstoreweight + totalstorecubicfeet); 
}
```

Notice the two changed lines are:

```
OdbcCommand getcartons = new OdbcCommand("select chcasn, chstor, chacwt from wm242basd.chcart00 where chldno = '0010585567' and chstor = :storeNumber", odbccon);  
getcartons.AddParameter("storeNumber", storenumber);
```

Also, if you are using Visual Studio and you can connect to the DB from you local machine, this would be easy to debug.  Just put a break point in each one of the loops and see what the results of the queries are.